# I need simple logic help to add number fetched from template in ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need simple logic help, I am fetching data from the template and want to add a constant number every time in a method, but the number is getting squared in my logic. I am doing a simple angular project, to make me understand concepts.

```
onAddDailyItems(content: any) {
  const costOfItem: number = content.amount;
  content.amount = content.amount + costOfItem;
  ++content.quantity;
}
```

I want result as

1. 100 + 0 = 100
2. 100 + 100 = 200
3. 100 + 200 = 300

Comment: What is the constant number you want to add?

Comment: Maybe `costOfItem` should be 100?!

Comment: @JonasWilms Yes, how to make costOfItem to remain constant value for that particular array, like so 100 at every press of a button, but it should be dynamic for every next item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take out the code from the function and use condition not equal to zero for example

```
costOfItem: number = 0;
onAddDailyItems(content: any) {
      if(this.costOfItem == 0) this.costOfItem = content.amount;
      content.amount = content.amount + costOfItem;
      ++content.quantity;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Such a simple solution and I was like what am I missing, why am I not getting this.